# SSRS Creating a Matrix for each category and page break between them

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm trying to do 2 things:

1. Create a matrix that will dynamically regenerate itself for each category in my dataset  (could be 2 categories, could be 10)
2. Create a page break between each one.

So as a visual, something along the lines of this.

```
CATEGORY (HEADER)
EMPLOYEE NAME (Details)

---- PAGE BREAK -----
```

Which would look like something this:

```
NEW YORK
John        etc...
Jim         etc...
Liz         etc...

---- page break -----

VERMONT
Jack        etc...
Sue         etc...
Tom         etc...
Phil        etc...

---- page break -----

TEXAS
Brian      etc...
Greg       etc...
```

Can someone help me understand how to build a single matrix for each category (State in this example) in my dataset ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can add a page break between each category. Go to category group properties in the `Page Break` tab, select `Between each instance of a group`.

Comment: Thanks this worked you rule!  Not sure how to give you credit for the correct answer

Comment: @alejandrozuleta could post it as an answer instead of as a comment and then you could accept that answer :-)

Comment: @Jay, I've posted an answer, you can close the question giving positive feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a page break between each category. Go to `Category` group properties in the `Page Break` tab, select `Between each instance of a group`.

[image]